# gulp-webserver error occured sometimes

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

> events.js:85
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>               ^
>       Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
>           at errnoException (dns.js:44:10)
>           at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)

When I ran '`gulp`' command, I met this error, but I don't know how to solve it. I also meet this error when I ran `gulp serve` command, so I guess this error was caused by `gulp-webserver`.

My `gulp serve` task in `gulpfile.js` is here.

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
  gulp.src('app/')
     .pipe(webserver({
       livereload: true,
       directoryListening: true,
       open: true
     }));
});
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Look at your `/etc/hosts` file if it contains line: 127.0.0.1 localhost

Comment: I couldnt find hosts file in my Mac Yosemite...

Comment: For Yosemite: `/private/etc/hosts`. Reference: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158117/os-x-10-10-1-etc-hosts-private-etc-hosts-file-is-being-ignored-and-not-resol

Comment: yes, I searched there. but there is only hosts.equiv file.  Is this correct?

Comment: No, it have to be hosts without extension. Without it DNS would not resolve localhost name.

Comment: So if I dont have hosts file in there, I have to create this file in /private/etc/ ?

Comment: Yes, content you can grab from link I've provided above

Answer (score 1):

Problem was with `hosts` file on Mac Yosemite. To correct behavior in `/private/etc/hosts` was added following line:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```